# How to find out whether a dynamically created checkbox was checked or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a dynamic `CheckBox` at the `Page_Load` event in my ASP.NET website.

Here is the code

```
 public CheckBox[] chk;
 chk[i] = new CheckBox();
 chk[i].ID = "chk" + dt1.Rows[i]["SubjectName"].ToString();
 chk[i].Text = dt1.Rows[i]["SubjectName"].ToString();                   
 PanelSubject.Controls.Add(chk[i]);
```

How can I later find out if a `CheckBox` created this way was checked by user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register event for that dynamically created check box like below :

```
 public CheckBox[] chk;
 chk[i] = new CheckBox();
 chk[i].ID = "chk" + dt1.Rows[i]["SubjectName"].ToString();
 chk[i].Text = dt1.Rows[i]["SubjectName"].ToString();                   
 chk[i].CheckedChanged += WebForm1_CheckedChanged;
 PanelSubject.Controls.Add(chk[i]);


 void WebForm1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```

Also you need to keep `chk[i].AutoPostBack = true;`

Answer (score 1):

Use `javascript`

In your script :

```
    var x=document.getElementById("IdCheckbox").checked
if(x==1)
{
//checked
}
else
{
// unchecked
}
```

or

```
function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('idofcheckbox').checked) {
            alert("checked");
        } else {
            alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
        }
    }
```

or if you are using jquery then

```
if($("#idofcheckbox").is(':checked'))
      // checked
else
     // unchecked
```

another method

```
$("#idcheckbox").attr("checked") ? alert("Checked") : alert("Unchecked");
```

Answer (score 1):

since all of the checkboxes are in a panel and you have assigned IDs to all of the checkboxes, you can just use the  method  Findcontrol  which find controls within the panel by ID

```
    string SubjectName = dt1.Rows[i]["SubjectName"].ToString();

    CheckBox currentCheckBox = PanelSubject.FindControl("chk" + SubjectName) as CheckBox;
    if( currentCheckBox !=null   )
    {
         if( currentCheckBox.Checked )
         {
             //here is your code 
             string alertMessage = string.Format("Subject {0} is checked !!!", SubjectName );
         }
     }
```